# HowTo Block WiFi Signal But Let Cell Phone Signal Pass Through

Tags: wireless-networking

I am operating an internet cafe. With WiFi WPA2 but people nearby can still get the password because they can come and see it in Windows.

Anyway, what I like to do is: use something to block the wifi signal but still allow the cell phone inside to work, any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with people can come and see it in windows?

Comment: because it's an internet cafe, they can come as client and use the PC with Windows, and see the password in wireless settings.

Comment: @EricYin - Your statment makes no sense.  They could use any personal electronic device to get the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking wifi from escaping without blocking cell phone can not be done, however there are other options for keeping people from unauthorized access to the WiFi.

What you will need to do is set up a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). After the user connects to your wireless the user will not be able to connect to anything other than the server's login page until they type in a username and password.

Once you have individual logins you can start logging and tracking how often and how long people are logged in. If you see someone is connected for 24 Hours you know they are stealing your WiFi and you can ban them. If you see a login that happens every day but you know that person is not a regular that does not come in every day you can ban that too.

You may be able to replace your WiFi access point's firmware with a replacement firmware, [CoovaAP](http://www.coova.org/CoovaAP) is a example of a firmware that is specifically designed to be used in situations exactly like yours.

Comment: I have drastically updated my question, RAIDUS is not a good solution. but a captive  portal is perfect for what you are trying to do.